# Spring WebFlow flow registry inheritance

Tags: spring-webflow-2

I have this configuration:

```
<webflow:flow-registry id="parentFlowRegistry" flow-builder-services="mvcFlowBuilderServices">
    <!-- some flow location -->
</webflow:flow-registry>

<webflow:flow-registry id="childFlowRegistry" parent="parentFlowRegistry">
    <webflow:flow-location id="address/flow" path="/META-INF/address/flow" />
</webflow:flow-registry>

<bean id="flow" class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
    <property name="order" value="0" />
    <property name="flowRegistry" ref="childFlowRegistry" />
</bean>

<bean id="mvcFlowBuilderServices" class="org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.support.FlowBuilderServices">
    <property name="expressionParser" ref="expressionParser" />
    <property name="conversionService" ref="conversionService" />
    <property name="viewFactoryCreator" ref="mvcViewFactoryCreator" />
    <property name="development" value="${weblow.development}" />
</bean>

<webflow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor">
    <webflow:flow-execution-repository max-executions="1" max-execution-snapshots="15" />
    <webflow:flow-execution-attributes>
        <webflow:always-redirect-on-pause value="true" />
    </webflow:flow-execution-attributes>
</webflow:flow-executor>
```

When i go to the page that has the location "address/flow" i have this error:

```
`org.springframework.webflow.definition.registry.NoSuchFlowDefinitionException: No flow` definition 'address/flow' found
```

I would like to have many flow registry that have parentFlowRegistry as a parent.

Thank you

Comment: Did you see path is empty in flow-location?

Comment: Yes, error to copy here